# MVC form application access from mobile device

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership, mobile-devices

I have this MVC web application that generates and return XML file as a result. I also have mobile application that gets xml file from MVC web application. 
I have simplemembership as authentication for mvc web app and I want to use it with my mobile application without using web browser. How do I approach to implement such process?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use basic authentication where you send the credentials in the header of the HTML request. You need to use SSL/HTTPS on the server to make this secure. Here is an [article on how to use basic authentication with SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html).